# How to find/select consecutive records (occurring at least twice) in a table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have the following table with some simple data inside.

```
Table sample
Product   Date                    Sold
 A        29-04-2020 12:23:44PM   Y
 A        30-04-2020 12:39:31AM   N
 A        01-05-2020 03:25:49PM   N
 A        02-05-2020 05:16:30PM   Y
 A        03-05-2020 11:11:51AM   N
 A        04-05-2020 12:39:31AM   N
 A        05-05-2020 12:20:40AM   Y
 A        06-05-2020 06:10:56AM   N
 A        07-05-2020 12:01:03PM   N
 A        08-05-2020 10:40:45AM   N
 A        09-05-2020 12:22:49AM   Y
 A        10-05-2020 12:01:12AM   Y
 A        11-05-2020 07:29:22PM   N
 A        12-05-2020 01:58:59AM   Y
 A        13-05-2020 10:21:47PM   Y
```

All I need it to do is return count(A) where each Sold = 'N' and where the day before was also Sold = 'N'. The time is also important, because it needs to select the day before, and not just the DAY-24 hours. So '07-05-2020 12:01:03PM' would still be selected even though '06-05-2020 06:10:56AM' is more than 1 day old.

EXPECTED OUTPUT: (4) example:

```
Table sample
Product   Date                    Sold
 A        01-05-2020 03:25:49PM   N
 A        04-05-2020 12:39:31AM   N
 A        07-05-2020 12:01:03PM   N
 A        08-05-2020 10:40:45AM   N
```

I have tried using 2 tables: `SELECT count(o1.product) FROM sample o1, sample o2 WHERE (o1.date >= o2.date-1) AND o1.sold = 'N' AND o2.sold = 'N'` However this doesn't work out for me.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Call me stupid but I'm not actually sure. I'm using another program to query an SQL database. I believe it's SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the previous *sold* is 'N' and the previous *date* is from yesterday:

```
with cte as
 (
   select
      product
     ,date
     ,sold
     -- previous "sold"
     ,lag(sold) over (partition by product order by date) as prev_sold
     -- previous "date" truncating the time portion
     ,cast(lag(date) over (partition by product order by date) as date) as prev_date
   from myTable
 )
select *
from cte
where sold = 'N'
  and prev_sold = 'N'
  and cast(date as date)= dateadd(day, 1, prev_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although dnoeth has a good solution, you can do this with only one window function:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by product, sold order by date) as prev_n_date
      from t
      where sold = 'N'
     ) t
where convert(date, date) = dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, prev_n_date));
```

This looks at the previous date that was "N" and checks if it is the day before.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5312255d8f7af3e28eff06dfd88a4243) is a db<>fiddle.

Notes:  This logic gets a bit tricker if you have multiple rows per day.  If that is an issue, ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of the logic to handle multiple values on one day.

Comment: There's no need for the outer `where sold = 'N'`

Comment: @dnoeth . . . That is so true.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this modify/update/remove anything from the original database at all? By using partition/over /lag/convert ? Sorry but I'm only just looking up the definitions of these operators now.

Comment: @M.Owen . . . `SELECT` statements do not modify the database.  You need an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

following should in SQL Server and MySQL 8, here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a16689a5d5dd9b4749f94ec9809d1a5).

```
with cte as
(
  select
      product,
      date,
      sold,
      lag(sold) over (partition by rnk order by date) as nrnk
  from
  (
    select
        *,
        dateadd(day, - row_number() over(order by date), date) as rnk
     from myTable
     where sold = 'N'
  ) val
)

select 
  product,
  date,
  sold
from cte
where nrnk = 'N'
```

output:

```
---------------------------
| product  date      sold |
--------------------------- 
|  A     2020-05-01    N  |
|  A     2020-05-04    N  |
|  A     2020-05-07    N  |
|  A     2020-05-08    N  |
---------------------------
```